# on button click, highlight entire contents of textbox (youtube share)

Tags: javascript, html

i have many posts all with unique statusid numbers associated with them. 
each post has a 'share' button and a textfield with the current posts unique url in the textfield value.

i want this 'share' buton, on click, to highlight the url text of the accompanying textbox, which is unique to its post

so far i have this butt it isnt working

```
<input type="button" value="share" onclick="shareurl"> 
article address:<input type="text" value="blog.php?id='.$statusid.'" name="urlbox'.$statusid.'">


function shareurl(statusid) {
   ("urlbox"+statusid).focus();
   ("urlbox"+statusid).select();
}
```

statusid is unique to each post so im trying to use that to only highlight the correct textbox url

Comment: You're missing the `()` on your method call

Comment: are you using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you may follow the following [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/bajeyoyedo/1/) which is a native [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) solution, i.e it does not need any third party libraries such as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    function sel(id){
      ob = document.getElementById(id);
      ob.select();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="i" type="text" value="somthing to be selected" />
  <input type="button" value="select" onclick="sel('i')" />
</body>
</html>
```

You define the input field by an `id` then make a function to get the `input field` object and finally apply the method `select()`